# Create a Map using Stream from List<Stream<String>>

Tags: java, methods, java-stream

I need to create a `Map<String, Stream<String>>  phoneNums(List<Stream<String>> numsList)` method to build a `Map` of all phone numbers.

The key of `Map` is code of network and value contains sorted list of phones.

Also need to remove all spaces, brackets and dashes from phone numbers.

For example for given:

```
 ["093 987 65 43", "(050)1234567",   
       "12-345"],    ["067-21-436-57", "050-2345678", "0939182736",   
       "224-19-28"],    ["(093)-11-22-334", "044 435-62-18", "721-73-45"]
```

I should get:

```
{   "050"=["1234567", "2345678"],    
"067"=["2143657"],   
   "093"=["1122334", "9182736", "9876543"],    
"044"=["4356218"],   
   "loc"=["2241928", "7217345"],    
"err"=["12345"] }
```

And I'm stuck right here. Please help.

```
public Map<String, Stream<String>> phoneNums(List<Stream<String>> numsList) {
    return numsList.stream()
                   .flatMap(Function.identity())
                   .map(l ->l.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""))
                   .filter(n -> n.length()==10)
                   .map(n ->n.substring(0,3))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap());
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start:

```
return numsList.stream()
               .flatMap(Function.identity())
               .map(l ->l.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""))
```

But then you discard all the “error” numbers, and then you discard the local part of the number, so all that’s left is the area code:

```
               .filter(n -> n.length()==10)
               .map(n ->n.substring(0,3))
```

You need to keep all numbers, so you must not use `filter` at all.  Instead, you need to keep the entire number and make it available to the `groupingBy` method, then choose a Map key based on the number’s length.

Joop is correct that Map values should not be Streams, since Streams can only be read once; `Map<String, List<String>>` makes more sense:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> phoneNums(List<Stream<String>> numsList) {
    return numsList.stream()
                   .flatMap(Function.identity())
                   .map(l -> l.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""))
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                       n -> n.length() == 10 ? n.substring(0, 3)
                           : (n.length() == 7 ? "loc" : "err"),
                       Collectors.mapping(
                           n -> n.length() == 10 ? n.substring(3) : n,
                           Collectors.toList())));
}
```

The above logic uses the area code for a key if the length is 10;  "loc" if the length is 7;  "err" for any other length.

If you really *need* to return Streams as Map values, you can change the last line to:

```
                           Collectors.toList().stream())));
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps me!
Wasn't really understand how to write .groupingBy, but you make it clear.
 Solved

Answer (score 0):

Stream is a once-only iteration. Thus a `Map<String, List<String>>` is what you will get. With `List#stream()` you could turn every List into a Stream, but besides the operational loss, restricting oneself one gains nothing.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> phoneNums(List<Stream<String>> numsList) {
    return numsList.stream()
                   .flatMap(Function.identity())
                   .map(l ->l.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""))
                   .filter(n -> n.length() == 10)
                   .groupingBy(n -> n.substring(0, 3), // Key.
                       n -> n.substring(3)); // Value.
}
```

`groupingBy` generates a List, but with adding a third optional parameter you might generate a Stream. But future colleagues will find it harder to read.